# How to list the files larger than 1 GB in a SVN repository

Tags: linux, svn

I need a command to list the files larger than 1GB  in a SVN repository. How do i achieve that, it would be great if someone can help me with the exact command.

I'm using a command line client to achieve this.

Thanks for your help.

Edited Content:

I tried this command:

```
svn list --verbose --recursive file://path/to/repo | du -sh * | grep G
```

Is this command safe to return the files which are bigger than 1 gig or do we have any alternate command to run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`du -sh *` isn't what you want.  It will operate on the current directory, not on the list provided via standard input.  You have the right general idea, though.

`svn list -v -R file://path/to/repo >svnlist.txt` will create a text file containing details about every file in the repo.  The third item in each line is the file size, in bytes.  What you want to do is to filter out all lines that have a third field with a value of 1073741824 or more.

```
gig=$(( 1024*1024*1024 ))
while read line
do
    size=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
    [[ $size -ge $gig ]] && echo $line
done <svnlist.txt
```

This uses `awk` to extract the third field, which is the size (in bytes).  If this value is greater than the pre-computed value of a gigabyte, then it prints out the entire line which contains the file's size and path.  Directories present a problem because they don't have a size field.  In their case, `size` will end up containing the name of a month.  Due to the way that text and numbers compare lexically, the `if` should always evaluate false in this case.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the reply, Let me try this and get back to you on the response.

Comment: Just curious, is there any other way to achieve this? apart from writing the output to a text file and fetching it from it?

Comment: You should be able to skip the temp file and pipe the output of the svn command into the rest of the code.  You're potentially looking at a large amount of output from the 'svn list' command, though, so I recommend using the intermediate file.  That's typically a less problematic way to forward large amounts of data.